# Delay in change of action jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, symfony

I am working on a project in Symfony. I have a table with some rows, and the end of each row there are four options. Based on the option chosen in each row, I want the color of the entire row to change. Now, this code works fine on jsfiddle, but however in my project, for each row, when I choose some option for the first time, there is no effect, the color does not change. When I choose some option the second time, the color changes. This is applicable for all rows. I want the color to change the first time itself like it is happening in jsfiddle. Link here: https://jsfiddle.net/wqeob4jo/2/

PS: I am using REACT JS

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').change(function() {
    var selectedVal = this.value;
    if (selectedVal == "2") {
      $(this).closest('tr').removeClass().addClass('not_wanted')
    } else if (selectedVal == "3") {
      $(this).closest('tr').removeClass().addClass('not_available')
    } else if (selectedVal == "4") {
      $(this).closest('tr').removeClass().addClass('vacation')
    } else if (selectedVal == "5") {
      $(this).closest('tr').removeClass().addClass('priority_off')
    }
  });
});
```

```css
table td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-left: 100px;
}
th {
  color: black;
}
tr.not_wanted {
  color: red;
}
tr.not_available {
  color: blue;
}
tr.vacation {
  color: orange;
}
tr.priority_off {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
  <tr style="background-color:grey;">
    <th>Col 1</th>
    <th>Col 2</th>
    <th>Col 3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="options">
    <td>Date 1</td>
    <td>Date 2</td>
    <td>
      <select id="select">
        <option value="2">not_wanted</option>
        <option value="3">not_available</option>
        <option value="4">vacation</option>
        <option value="5">priority_off</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="options">
    <td>Date 1</td>
    <td>Date 2</td>
    <td>
      <select id="select">
        <option value="2">not_wanted</option>
        <option value="3">not_available</option>
        <option value="4">vacation</option>
        <option value="5">priority_off</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Could there be another piece of javascript conflicting with your color change code in the Symfony project? See no reason why it would not work on Symfony first time when it works on jsFiddle unless there's a conflict / code is different.

Comment: I have no clue. It is no doubt loaded dynamically through some javascript code but I am not able to figure out where exactly the problem is occurring.

Comment: Try adding a `console.log` line inside the callback function and look in your console for the message? If it's triggering first time but no color change happens would be a good starting point.

Comment: if it is loading dynamically try to use jquery "on" and then pass your event. something like this $('select').on('change',function () {  // your code here });

Comment: or put a break point and see whether your change event is firing or not on the first time when you change the dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this issue by using

```
$(document).on('change','#select',function () {...
```

instead of

```
$('select').change(function() {...
```

full function:

```
$(document).on('change','#select',function () {
    var selectedVal = this.value;
    if (selectedVal == "2") {
      $(this).closest('tr').removeClass().addClass('not_wanted');
    } else if (selectedVal == "3") {
      $(this).closest('tr').removeClass().addClass('not_available');
    } else if (selectedVal == "4") {
      $(this).closest('tr').removeClass().addClass('vacation');
    } else if (selectedVal == "5") {
      $(this).closest('tr').removeClass().addClass('priority_off');
    }
  });
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Sorry, but this has nullified even the subsequent effects. This is not working.

Comment: I don't follow. works great both in JS fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wqeob4jo/4/ and in a local HTML on my computer.